# In Visual Studio 2019, The Name Of The Scenario In Test Explorer Is Different From The Test That I Want To Run

Tags: automated-testing, visualstudio, bdd, specflow

The test scenario in Test Explorer is different from what I have in my V/S Project.

I have tried re-starting Test Explorer to no effect.  Thanks !

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feels like the generation of the code behind is not working correctly. Specflow creates `.cs` file for each `.feature` file. This .cs file contains the "real" testcode that is found by the test-explorer. Each should be regenerated on each save, rebuild.

We had to set the option "specflowsinglefilegenerator" to true. Suggest you try the options in the following two pages:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57684709/i-cannot-get-specflows-code-behind-files-to-regenerate
- https://specflow.org/2019/generating-code-behind-files-using-msbuild/

Alternatively, delete the generated .cs files and rebuild your project.

Comment: That Fixed The Issue.. Arigato !